# Center the vertical middle of displayfield and button in hbox

Tags: extjs

Please help me vertically center the button with the label and value.  Why does "align: 'middle'" not cause the button text to appear at the same level as the displayfield content?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1et9

Comment: They are aligned, the field just a different height to the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply fixed heights for both fields and use line-height to align center

```js
items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'displayfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'My Label',
                        labelWidth: 200,
                        height: '40',
                        value: 'My Value',
                        labelStyle: 'line-height:24px;',
                        fieldStyle: 'line-height:24px;'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 40,
                        text: 'too low'
                    }
                ]
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1eu1

Comment: Thank you!  Your Fiddle didn't work, but I used the intel to fix mine.  I saved it here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1eu8
If you make your Fiddle work, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Somehow some config got missing from my fiddle. Changed  all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe custom CSS style will be enough:

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'My Label',
    labelWidth: 200,
    value: 'My Value',
    style: 'padding-top: 8px;' // - custom style
}
```